# using php preg_replace to replace a whole character string and not replace if string is part of a longer string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Regular Expressions are completely new to me and having done much searching my expression for testing purposes is this:

```
preg_replace('/\b0.00%\b/','- ', '0.00%')
```

It yields `0.00%` when what I want is `-` .

With `preg_replace('/\b0.00%\b/','- ', '50.00%')` yields `50.00%` which is what I want - so this is fine.

But clearly the expression is not working as it is not, in the first example replacing `0.00%` with `-`.

I can think of workarounds with `if(){}` for testing length/content of string but presume the replace will be most efficient

Comment: You do not understand what a word boundary is. You need to use `\B` at the end, not `\b`, if you need to match when the `%` is followed with a non-word char or at the end of string.

Comment: Do `0.00%` and `50.00%` represent the full input string or are these values part of larger strings? So far, it looks like you don't need a regular expression at all. @paul

Comment: the % character is part of the string values such as 0.00%  50.00%  15.87% are the full string - not part of a larger string and with no other characters before or after.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the point of using `preg_replace` to change the full string? Just use `if ($s=='0.00%') { return '- '; }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - an opportunity to understand regex and an assumption that it will be faster over multiple iterations (thousands of lines in a php generated report) - what do you think?

Comment: But what do you want then? `preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($value, '/') . '\z/i', '- ', $str)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) after `%` requires a word char (letter, digit or `_`) to appear right after it, so there is no replacement taking place here.

You need to replace the word boundaries with unambiguous boundaries defined with the help of `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` lookarounds that will fail the match if the keywords are preceded or followed with word characters:

```
$value='0.00%';
$str = 'Price: 0.00%';
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\w)' . preg_quote($value, '/') . '(?!\w)/i', '- ', $str);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/lrcXQR)

Output: `Price: -`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew  - this has worked really well thank you.  I did also try if ($s=='0.00%') { return '- '; } but this seemed to interfere with complex nested counters - so no chance to compare performance.  Really appreciate your detailed understanding - very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace has three arguments as you probably already know. The regular expression pattern to match, the replacement value, and the string to search (in that order).

It appears that your preg_replace regex pattern has word boundries `\b` it is looking for on either end of the value you are looking for `0.00%` which should not really be needed. This looks a bit like a bug to me especially when I plug it into the [regex website](https://regex101.com/) I use. It works fine there. There is probably a somewhat odd querk with it so you might want to try it without the `\b` and try something like the start of string `^` and end of string characters `$`.