# Using preg_replace() with search words that may have special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to use `preg_replace` to replace a term according to the following rules:

- the search term that shall be replaced can contain the following characters: `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` `.` `@` `(` `)`. More precisely, `()` may only be the final two characters of the search term but they are optional. They can be there, but it's not a must. The initial character must be `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `@`. The `.` may not be in initial or final position.
- the search term shall be considered a word, i.e. there should only be a match if the search term is delimited by characters that can be used to separate words, e.g. whitespace (space, TAB, linefeed) or `.` or `,` and so on.

Now my problem is that my search term can contain word-delimiting characters like `.` or `(` or `)`. I'm not really sure how to deal with this. I don't think I can use `\b` because this would break on word-delimiting characters like `.`, `(` or `)`.

Can anybody help?

***EDIT***

Here are some example strings:

```
$str = 'This is a little() test!';
$str = 'This is a @little test!";
$str = 'This is a nice.little test!";
```

Now I want to replace `little()`, `@little`, or `nice.little` by `big` for instance.

Comment: Try [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012362/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I don't understand. What do `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` actually do?

Comment: Unambiguous word boundaries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Nice, it seems to do the trick. I'll do some more testing.

Comment: Please let me know if that does not cover all the test cases and if you need a different solution. Note that other solutions include whitespace boundaries (also a solved issue), `(?<!\S)` / `(?!\S)` lookarounds.